# Application.exit() calls FormClosingEvent of different Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I have a C# application that has multiple forms. On every form I have Cancel button and the top right (x) button. For every form, I have created a cancelButton_Click() which goes like this:

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

This one calls the formClosing function which goes like this:

```
private void FormLoginPage_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   string exitMessageText = "Are you sure you want to exit the application?";
   string exitCaption = "Cancel";
   MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
   DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(exitMessageText, exitCaption, button, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
   if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
       e.Cancel = false;

   }
   else if (res == DialogResult.No)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

Similarly I have created customized formClosing functions for all forms, since I want to handle Closing events differently for all forms.

However, when I click on Cancel button for say Form2, the control goes to Form1 Closing event function. 
Is there a better way to implement this? Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I tried using e.CloseReason to check for ApplicationExit, but i cannot use this in every FormClosing event function,  since it will also bypass the FormClosing function of existing form. Please help!

Comment: for the current form call Close, in the event handler `FormLoginPage_Closing` call `Application.Exit()`

Comment: I did just that, using Application.Exit() in say Form2_Closing calls Form1_Closing, which again has a messageBox for exiting application. I hance get multiple messageBoxes and i go back and forth between the 2 forms Closing events due to Application.Exit()

Comment: And you checked for e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplcationExit at the top of the Form2_Closing method?

Comment: Now I did, and it worked perfectly! This is how I went about it: Call Close() in every CancelButtonClick(), check for .CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplcationExit at the top of every FormClosing method, and call Application.Exit() when DialogResult.Yes for the CancelDialog Box. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class something like

```
public static class ApplicationCloseHelper
{
    public static void CloseApplication()
    {
        if (UserIsSure())
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private static bool UserIsSure()
    {    
        string exitMessageText = "Are you sure you want to exit the application?";
        string exitCaption = "Cancel";
        MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(exitMessageText, exitCaption, button, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return res == DialogResult.Yes;
    }
}
```

then remove the `Form_Closing` event handlers and call

```
ApplicationCloseHelper.CloseApplication();
```

directly from `Cancel_Click();`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is a better way you can do what you trying to achieve, just do as follows:

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void FormLoginPage_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   string exitMessageText = "Are you sure you want to exit the application?";
   string exitCaption = "Cancel";
   MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
   DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(exitMessageText, exitCaption, button, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
   if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
       e.Cancel = false;
       Application.Exit();
   }
   else if (res == DialogResult.No)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
   }

}
```

that way you first close the current form which is intuitive to the user and only after that you close the application which will trigger the closing events of the other forms.

Comment: IsClosing must be globally accessible, e.g Program.IsClosing static bool

Comment: yeah sorry - I revised my answer few times - was confused with WPF.. now it is good :)

Comment: I know, I'm trying to keep my comment up to date with your answer :) Currently that will only close the current form unless the form is the main form of the application

Comment: Tried the above code snippet, this one works well except that the application does not shut down completely; the process still runs.

Comment: My bad, I missed Application.Exit() under DialogResult.Yes. However, calling Application.Exit() still doesn't help me, because the control just moves back and forth between the two FormClosing Event functions.